# Logging/dumping data in JavaScript using AngularJS, Karma and Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

So normally when I need to log data in JavaScript, I simply `log` it to the console via `console.log("What I ate yesterday");`

Today, I was [watching a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVw8N3hTfCI) on Karma/Jasmine unit testing for AngularJS, and Vojta Jína, the host, [logged data using `window.dump`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVw8N3hTfCI#t=6m17s).

What value does this form of logging provide over simply using `console.log`? [This article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.dump?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.dump), from MDN, talks about a `dump` function on `window`, but this is actually logging directly in my terminal window, where my tests are running. I also found an article in the [docs on AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.dump) about how to `dump`, but I'm still not clear this is the kind of logging that Vojta Jina used in the initial video.

I'm hoping somebody can explain to me the kind of logging that Vojta uses, and possibly point me to some documentation (if it's different than what I outlined above) on some of the finer points of proper logging in JS.

Comment: did you go thru the code in tastaculor?

Comment: In Karma (specifically `/reporters/Base.js`, I see the onBrowserDump where it's actually dumping out to the terminal (same file, `this.adapters = [adapter || process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout)];` for example ... so that leads me to believe it's something related to browser dumping, which leads me back to my question. What is that? How does it work? For clarity, I'm using Chrome as my browser in Karma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like window.dump with redirection  see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.dom.window.dump.file

> browser.dom.window.dump.file redirects the ouput of window.dump()
>   calls to a file whose address is specified in this preference if
>   browser.dom.window.dump.enabled is set to true. Changes require an
>   application restart.

So I guess you can bind the dump to any output stream.

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.dump

> On Windows, you will need a console to actually see anything. If you
>   don't have one already, closing the application and re-opening it with
>   the command line parameter -console should create the console. On
>   other operating systems, it's enough to launch the application from a
>   terminal.
>
> To redirect the console output to a file, run firefox without the
>   -console option and use the syntax to redirect stderr and stdout to a file, i.e.:
>
> firefox > console.txt 2>&1
>
> If you would like the console messages to appear in the console you
>   used to launch the application, you can use the Gecko Console
>   Redirector

[See this](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&hl=en&q=site%3ahttp://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse%20%22dump%28%22&oq=site%3ahttp://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse%20%22dump%28%22&gs_l=serp.3...3485.3485.0.3787.1.1.0.0.0.0.172.172.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c..14.serp.fCmzJ6vwB3U) and [this](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&hl=en&q=site%3ahttp://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse%20%22dump%28%22) in the chrome java script engine v8 too

Comment: Yeah I already referenced the second article in my question. But I only see this as specific to Firefox. I was using Chrome via Karma.

Comment: am sure its the same. they have had some time now to standardize this?

Comment: http://sel2in.com/g.html using this search in v8 (chrome javascript engine) its there too. added new links to see

Comment: Right on, thanks. For what it's worth. I don't think we should be dumping in any streams. But that's just me.

Comment: what is wrong with writing (possibly) large amounts of data to a stream? Isn't that what they are there for?